# How to avoid stretched image with website_multi_image_zoom module?

Tags: css, image, odoo-8

We use Odoo 8.

I have installed the **website_multi_image_zoom** module to have multi images on product pages on the frontend.

The module is now working. But often the main image is stretched.

How could we avoid this?

[image]

Comment: Can you share your HTML and CSS?

Answer (score 1):

A fixed width and height is not going to work for every image proportion. On that img element try using a fixed pixel width, or width: 100%; then use height: auto;. That way the different images will keep their true proportions and still fit the width of the container.

If that does not work then you can try a fixed container size and use background image contain or cover like described here https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background-size/

Comment: thanks for your answer. I will analyse it and I will come back soon.

Answer (score 0):

I have commented this line in the file multizoom.js of the module website_multi_image_zoom for Odoo 8.

```
//$imgObj.attr('src', this.src).css({width: w || options.width || this.width, height: (h = +(h || options.height || this.height))});
```

This line set a fixed height and width for the main image on load.

Now, images are not stretched.

Thanks all